# Scrolling a Linearlayout (Android App programming)

Tags: android, android-layout

I already read a lot about scrolling a Linearlayout, but nothing helped yet.
It says you can simply put it in a ScrollView, but whenever i do that, my app crashes when i try to start it. Thats my Sourcecode of the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Scrollview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/lout"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/bg"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</Scrollview>
```

I always get an error which says that the app failed to inflate the class ScrollView.
If i knew what that exactly mean, i may be able to solve the problem on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
<Scrollview
```

small "v". Change that to

```
<ScrollView
```

You will also need to change the end tag

```
</ScrollView>
```

Error inflating class  means just what it says. It can't find a class with that name here it is because the capitalization is wrong.

Comment: god damn.. when I explained my problem I wrote it right, but in the code I did it wrong !? Whats going on with me.. Thanks dude ! it works now :)

Comment: No problem, it happens. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left so it may help others easier.